# Provision Digitalocean instance using Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am trying to provision a digital ocean droplet using Terraform. I appear to be missing the host argument in the connection block, but am not certain what value I need for digitalocean.

This is my configuration file:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "test" {                                                                                                                                 
   image = "ubuntu-18-04-x64"                                                                                                                                           
   name = "test"                                                                                                                                                        
   region = "nyc1"                                                                                                                                                      
   size = "512mb"                                                                                                                                                       
   private_networking = true                                                                                                                                            
   ssh_keys = [                                                                                                                                                         
   "${var.ssh_fingerprint}"                                                                                                                                             
  ]                                                                                                                                                                      

  connection {                                                                                                                                                           
    user = "root"                                                                                                                                                      
    type = "ssh"                                                                                                                                                       
    private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"                                                                                                                           
    timeout = "2m"                                                                                                                                                     
  }                                                                                                                                                                      

  provisioner "remote-exec" {                                                                                                                                            
    inline = [                                                                                                                                                         
      "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin",                                                                                                                                    
      # install nginx                                                                                                                                                  
      "sudo apt-get update",                                                                                                                                           
      "sudo apt-get -y install nginx"                                                                                                                                  
    ]                                                                                                                                                                  
  }                                                                                                                                                                      

}
```

"terraform validate" gives me the error:

> Error: Missing required argument
>
> on frontend.tf line 11, in resource "digitalocean_droplet" "test":
>     11:   connection {
>
> The argument "host" is required, but no definition was found.

Answer (score 2):

I fiddled around with this and found the answer.

In the connection block we should have the host as:

```
connection {
     user = "root"
     type = "ssh"
     host = "${self.ipv4_address}"
     private_key = "${file(var.pvt_key)}"
     timeout = "2m"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly reference the exported var:

```
connection {
  user     = "root"
  host     = "${digitalocean_droplet.test.ipv4_address}"
  type     = "ssh"
  password = "${file(var.pvt_key)}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your syntax.

Try to use like below:

```
private_key = file("/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa")
```

I'm using terraform version 0.12.25

Best of luck.